# htaccess match url by category name

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, model-view-controller, url-rewriting

I am working on custom MVC patter in php which has following url implementation

> www.test.com/module/controller/action?params

And by php i am splitting url to find modules,controllers,action. It works well.

I have the situation to show the url like `www.test.com/sale`. Previously my url was `www.test.com?id=1` where id is category `sale` and it will call respective module,controller,action by php scripting.

I am using following htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My rewrite change should not affect existing flow and I need to specifically apply rewrite condition when i hit url `www.test.com/sale` it should call `www.test.com?id=1` like wise i can use for any other category.

Comment: Is `/sale` the only category or you have more?

Comment: @anubhava i have more than one category.

Comment: In that case rewrite rules cannot translate category to id by looking up some database

Comment: @anubhava only 3 categories, so i just want to do it in htaccess it self.IS it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^sale/?$ index.php?id=1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^purchase/?$ index.php?id=2 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ index.php?id=3 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: when i hit http://localhost/test/sale , it goes to wamp index page. also existing url goes wamp page

Comment: got it after remove rewriteBase / :) Thanks